# How to pass k8s secret key value into Jenkins via Declarative pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I want to pass Kubernetes secret key and value in the Jenkins job using a Declarative pipeline.

I am trying to read the k8s secret values using the pod template.
Configured the k8s plugin and the image has environment variables set. I need to overwrite the environment values with the k8s secret.

## K8S-Secret:

```
spec:
 containers:
   - env:
      - name: K8S-SECRET
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: USERNAME
              name: PASSWORD
```

## Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            label 'docker'
            envVars: [containersecretEnvVar(key: 'USERNAME', value:'PASSWORD')]
        }
    }
    environment {
      BRANCH = 'origin/master'
      PROJECT_NAME = 'k8s'
    }
   stages{
      stage('print k8s secret'){
           steps {
               echo "k8s_secret_name: ${env.k8s_secret_name}"
               echo "k8s_secret_valie: ${env.k8s_secret_value}"
           }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: cloud provider on AWS. Using the latest version.

Comment: Getting this error with the below code snippet in the pipeline. 

`Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate {envVars=[@secretEnvVar(key=TOKEN,secretName=foo,secretKey=bar)]} for org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.ContainerTemplate`

`podTemplate(inheritFrom: 'docker',
        containers: [
        containerTemplate(
        
        envVars: [
            secretEnvVar(key: 'TOKEN', secretName: 'foo', secretKey: 'bar')
        ])
    ]
){
    node('docker') {
        stage('test'){
            sh "echo ${foo}"
        }
    }
}  
`

Comment: Could you please provide exact version? Please don't use term 'lastest' cause it is imprecise.

Comment: Able to fix it.

Comment: If you resolved your issue, consider posting it in answer section.

Comment: Solution: Below code is working for me
`podTemplate(inheritFrom: 'docker', containers: [
        containerTemplate(
        name: "jnlp",
        image: "<image_name>",
        envVars: [
            envVar(key: "NAME", value: "custom_env"),
            secretEnvVar(key: "SECRET_ENV", secretName: "K8S-SECRET", secretKey: "USERNAME")
        ])
    ]
){
    node(POD_LABEL) {
     step {
       sh 'echo ${TOKEN}'
        
`

Comment: Hi @Jwary cloud please share your LinkedIn I'd still I'm having same issue not able to resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify I am posting the Community wiki answer from comments' section.

To solve that problem Original Poster created the following code:

```yaml
podTemplate(inheritFrom: 'docker', containers: [ 
    containerTemplate( name: "jnlp", image: "<image_name>", 
        envVars: [ 
            envVar(key: "NAME", value: "custom_env"), 
            secretEnvVar(key: "SECRET_ENV", secretName: "K8S-SECRET", secretKey: "USERNAME") 
    ]) ] ){ 
    node(POD_LABEL) { 
        step { 
        sh 'echo ${TOKEN}'
        ...
        }   
    }
```

In this solution `PodTemplates` has been used. In [this documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) one can find more info about that:

> Pod templates are used to create agents. They can be either configured via the user interface, or in a pipeline, using the `podTemplate` step.

Here you can find how to [define a podTemplate to use in the kubernetes plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes/#podtemplate-define-a-podtemplate-to-use-in-the-kubernetes-plugin).

See also [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#pod-templates)  that describes `podTemplate`.

> Controllers for  [workload](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/)  resources create Pods from a  *pod template*  and manage those Pods on your behalf.
>
> PodTemplates are specifications for creating Pods, and are included in workload resources such as  [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/),  [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/), and  [DaemonSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).
>
> Each controller for a workload resource uses the  `PodTemplate`  inside the workload object to make actual Pods. The  `PodTemplate`  is part of the desired state of whatever workload resource you used to run your app.